# Why is it faster if I put an extra ToArray before ToLookup?

Tags: c#, linq

We have a short method that parse .csv file to a lookup:

```
ILookup<string, DgvItems> ParseCsv( string fileName )
{
    var file = File.ReadAllLines( fileName );
    return file.Skip( 1 ).Select( line => new DgvItems( line ) ).ToLookup( item => item.StocksID );
}
```

And the definition of DgvItems:

```
public class DgvItems
{
    public string DealDate { get; }

    public string StocksID { get; }

    public string StockName { get; }

    public string SecBrokerID { get; }

    public string SecBrokerName { get; }

    public double Price { get; }

    public int BuyQty { get; }

    public int CellQty { get; }

    public DgvItems( string line )
    {
        var split = line.Split( ',' );
        DealDate = split[0];
        StocksID = split[1];
        StockName = split[2];
        SecBrokerID = split[3];
        SecBrokerName = split[4];
        Price = double.Parse( split[5] );
        BuyQty = int.Parse( split[6] );
        CellQty = int.Parse( split[7] );
    }
}
```

And we found that if we add an extra `ToArray()` before `ToLookup()` like this:

```
static ILookup<string, DgvItems> ParseCsv( string fileName )
{
    var file = File.ReadAllLines( fileName  );
    return file.Skip( 1 ).Select( line => new DgvItems( line ) ).ToArray().ToLookup( item => item.StocksID );
}
```

The latter is significantly faster. More specifically, when use test file with 1.4 million lines, the former takes around 4.3 seconds and the latter takes around 3 seconds.

I expect `ToArray()` should take extra time so the latter should be slightly slower. Why is it actually faster?

---

Extra information:

1. We found this issue because there is another method that parse same .csv file to different format and it takes around 3 seconds so we think this one should be able to do the same thing in 3 seconds.
2. The original data type is `Dictionary<string, List<DgvItems>>` and the original code didn't use linq and the result is similar.

---

BenchmarkDotNet test class:

```
public class TestClass
{
    private readonly string[] Lines;

    public TestClass()
    {
        Lines = File.ReadAllLines( @"D:\20110315_Random.csv" );
    }

    [Benchmark]
    public ILookup<string, DgvItems> First()
    {
        return Lines.Skip( 1 ).Select( line => new DgvItems( line ) ).ToArray().ToLookup( item => item.StocksID );
    }

    [Benchmark]
    public ILookup<string, DgvItems> Second()
    {
        return Lines.Skip( 1 ).Select( line => new DgvItems( line ) ).ToLookup( item => item.StocksID );
    }
}
```

Result:

```
| Method |    Mean |    Error |   StdDev |
|------- |--------:|---------:|---------:|
|  First | 2.530 s | 0.0190 s | 0.0178 s |
| Second | 3.620 s | 0.0217 s | 0.0203 s |
```

---

I did another test base on original code. Seems that the problem is not on Linq.

```
public class TestClass
{
    private readonly string[] Lines;

    public TestClass()
    {
        Lines = File.ReadAllLines( @"D:\20110315_Random.csv" );
    }

    [Benchmark]
    public Dictionary<string, List<DgvItems>> First()
    {
        List<DgvItems> itemList = new List<DgvItems>();
        for ( int i = 1; i < Lines.Length; i++ )
        {
            itemList.Add( new DgvItems( Lines[i] ) );
        }

        Dictionary<string, List<DgvItems>> dictionary = new Dictionary<string, List<DgvItems>>();

        foreach( var item in itemList )
        {
            if( dictionary.TryGetValue( item.StocksID, out var list ) )
            {
                list.Add( item );
            }
            else
            {
                dictionary.Add( item.StocksID, new List<DgvItems>() { item } );
            }
        }

        return dictionary;
    }

    [Benchmark]
    public Dictionary<string, List<DgvItems>> Second()
    {
        Dictionary<string, List<DgvItems>> dictionary = new Dictionary<string, List<DgvItems>>();
        for ( int i = 1; i < Lines.Length; i++ )
        {
            var item = new DgvItems( Lines[i] );

            if ( dictionary.TryGetValue( item.StocksID, out var list ) )
            {
                list.Add( item );
            }
            else
            {
                dictionary.Add( item.StocksID, new List<DgvItems>() { item } );
            }
        }

        return dictionary;
    }
}
```

Result:

```
| Method |    Mean |    Error |   StdDev |
|------- |--------:|---------:|---------:|
|  First | 2.470 s | 0.0218 s | 0.0182 s |
| Second | 3.481 s | 0.0260 s | 0.0231 s |
```

Comment: I highly suspect the testing code/measuring. Please post the code that calculates the time

Comment: My guess is that without the `.ToArray()`, the call to `.Select( line => new DgvItems( line ) )` returns an IEnumerable before the call to `ToLookup( item => item.StocksID )`. And looking up a particular element is worse using IEnumerable than Array. Probably faster to convert to an array and perform lookup than using an ienumerable.

Comment: Side note: put `var file = File.ReadLines( fileName  );` - `ReadLines` instead of `ReadAllLines` and you code will probably be faster

Comment: You should use `BenchmarkDotnet` for actual perf measuring. Also, try and isolate the actual code you want to measure and not include IO in the test.

Comment: @JohanP I've tested with BenchmarkDotnet and update the result.

Comment: I don't know why this got a downvote - I think it's a good question.

Comment: Did you run the tests using .NET Framework or .NET Core?

Comment: I run it on both, the result is similar.

Comment: Does anyone reproduce same result?

Comment: On a side note, shouldn't the price be decimal instead of double?

Comment: Yes, it should be decimal.This is one of terrible design decisions made years ago and it's hard to change now because it's everywhere.

Answer (score 2):

I managed to replicate the issue with the simplified code below:

```
var lookup = Enumerable.Range(0, 2_000_000)
    .Select(i => ( (i % 1000).ToString(), i.ToString() ))
    .ToArray() // +20% speed boost
    .ToLookup(x => x.Item1);
```

It is important that the members of the created tuple are strings. Removing the two `.ToString()` from the above code eliminates the advantage of `ToArray`. The .NET Framework behaves a bit different than .NET Core, since it's enough to remove only the first `.ToString()` to eliminate the observed difference.

I have no idea why this happens.

Comment: Which framework did you confirm this with? I'm unable to see any difference using .net framework 4.7.2

Comment: @Magnus .NET Framework 4.8 (VS 2019, Release Build)

Comment: Initially I exaggerated the observed difference. It is around 20% in .NET Core, and around 10% in .NET Framework.

Comment: Nice repro. I have no specific knowledge of why this happens and do not have time to figure it out, but my *guess* would be that the `ToArray` or `ToList` forces data to be in contiguous memory; doing that forcing at a particular stage in the pipeline, even though it adds cost, may cause a later operation to have fewer processor cache misses; processor cache misses are surprisingly expensive.